# SQL Server Unexpected execution plan during delete operation

Tags: sql-server, performance

I've got a query like the following:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_Object 
WHERE ID = 3265;
```

When I run this query its is very slow and present a weird execution plan.
There's no cascade for in keys between both the tables.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would be so slow and how to speed it up?

Here is the execution plan:

[Weird execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CpTH.png)

Full details bellow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.2" Build="12.0.4213.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
<BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
    <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70" StatementSubTreeCost="0.0302709" StatementText="DELETE FROM FDN_AlertObject WHERE ID = 3265" StatementType="DELETE" ParameterizedText="(@1 smallint)DELETE [FDN_AlertObject]  WHERE [ID]=@1" QueryHash="0x5F72C08D4BF22BF4" QueryPlanHash="0x16D4813B4F8FB73E" RetrievedFromCache="false">
        <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
        <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="32" CompileTime="2" CompileCPU="2" CompileMemory="248">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="223696" EstimatedPagesCached="209715" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="4" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="1.8E-07" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Assert" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Assert" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0302709">
            <OutputList />
            <Assert StartupExpression="false">
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="4.18E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Left Semi Join" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0302707">
                <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
                </OutputList>
                <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                    <DefinedValues>
                    <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
                    </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <OuterReferences>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERTOBJECT]" Column="ID" />
                    </OuterReferences>
                    <ProbeColumn>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
                    </ProbeColumn>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="16" EstimateCPU="4.18E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Left Semi Join" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0267779">
                    <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERTOBJECT]" Column="ID" />
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
                    </OutputList>
                    <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                        <DefinedValues>
                        <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
                        </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <OuterReferences>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERTOBJECT]" Column="ID" />
                        </OuterReferences>
                        <ProbeColumn>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
                        </ProbeColumn>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="2E-06" EstimateIO="0.02" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Delete" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Delete" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0232851">
                        <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERTOBJECT]" Column="ID" />
                        </OutputList>
                        <SimpleUpdate DMLRequestSort="false">
                            <Object Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERTOBJECT]" Index="[PK__FDN_ALER__3214EC2790A10D93]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                            <Object Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERTOBJECT]" Index="[INDEX_ALERT_OBJECT_KEYS]" IndexKind="NonClustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                            <SeekPredicateNew>
                            <SeekKeys>
                                <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                <RangeColumns>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERTOBJECT]" Column="ID" />
                                </RangeColumns>
                                <RangeExpressions>
                                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@1],0)">
                                    <Convert DataType="bigint" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                            <ColumnReference Column="@1" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Convert>
                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                </RangeExpressions>
                                </Prefix>
                            </SeekKeys>
                            </SeekPredicateNew>
                        </SimpleUpdate>
                        </RelOp>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="11.7081" EstimateIO="25.3253" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="5" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00347834" TableCardinality="10643600">
                        <OutputList />
                        <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="true" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                            <DefinedValues />
                            <Object Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERT]" Index="[PK__FDN_ALER__3214EC273DF32C1B]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                            <Predicate>
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[my_DB].[dbo].[FDN_ALERT].[OBJECT_ID]=[my_DB].[dbo].[FDN_ALERTOBJECT].[ID]">
                                <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERT]" Column="OBJECT_ID" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERTOBJECT]" Column="ID" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                                </Compare>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                            </Predicate>
                        </IndexScan>
                        </RelOp>
                    </NestedLoops>
                    </RelOp>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="11.7081" EstimateIO="25.3253" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="6" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00347834" TableCardinality="10643600">
                    <OutputList />
                    <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="true" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                        <DefinedValues />
                        <Object Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERT]" Index="[PK__FDN_ALER__3214EC273DF32C1B]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                        <Predicate>
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[my_DB].[dbo].[FDN_ALERT].[PLACE_ID]=[my_DB].[dbo].[FDN_ALERTOBJECT].[ID]">
                            <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERT]" Column="PLACE_ID" />
                                </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                            <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[my_DB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[FDN_ALERTOBJECT]" Column="ID" />
                                </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                        </Predicate>
                    </IndexScan>
                    </RelOp>
                </NestedLoops>
                </RelOp>
                <Predicate>
                <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CASE WHEN NOT [Expr1008] IS NULL THEN (0) ELSE CASE WHEN NOT [Expr1009] IS NULL THEN (1) ELSE NULL END END">
                    <IF>
                    <Condition>
                        <ScalarOperator>
                        <Logical Operation="NOT">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                            <Logical Operation="IS NULL">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
                                </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                            </Logical>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                        </Logical>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                    </Condition>
                    <Then>
                        <ScalarOperator>
                        <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                        </ScalarOperator>
                    </Then>
                    <Else>
                        <ScalarOperator>
                        <IF>
                            <Condition>
                            <ScalarOperator>
                                <Logical Operation="NOT">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Logical Operation="IS NULL">
                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Logical>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                                </Logical>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                            </Condition>
                            <Then>
                            <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="(1)" />
                            </ScalarOperator>
                            </Then>
                            <Else>
                            <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="NULL" />
                            </ScalarOperator>
                            </Else>
                        </IF>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                    </Else>
                    </IF>
                </ScalarOperator>
                </Predicate>
            </Assert>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
            <ColumnReference Column="@1" ParameterCompiledValue="(3266)" />
            </ParameterList>
        </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
    </Statements>
    </Batch>
</BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Someone could help me to understand why?

Thank you.

Comment: Any delete triggers on the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Reason for a more complicated plan

You have foreign key references to `FDN_ALERTOBJECT`. So when you delete any row from `FDN_ALERTOBJECT`, the server needs to ensure you don't violate those constraints.

E.g. It has to check both `FDN_ALERT.OBJECT_ID` and `FDN_ALERT.PLACE_ID` to ensure that it doesn't have a reference to the `FDN_ALERTOBJECT.ID` you are trying to delete.

## Reason for poor performance

I don't see any indexes on `FDN_ALERT.OBJECT_ID` and `FDN_ALERT.PLACE_ID`. This means to check the constraints before deleting any rows from `FDN_ALERTOBJECT` requires at least 2 table-scans of the `FDN_ALERT` table in addition to any other processing required.

## To improve performance

Create the missing indexes. Note that SQL Server Management Studio has a built in tool to recommend missing indexes. If you had used it, it should have suggested the indexes below (and possibly others).

```
create index ixfk_Alert_ObjectId on FDN_ALERT (OBJECT_ID)
create index ixfk_Alert_PlaceId on FDN_ALERT (PLACE_ID)
```

SQL Server will update these indexes for each insert/update of `FDN_ALERT` with a small performance impact. However, they will have a big improvement on delete from `FDN_ALERTOBJECT`.